# Could not create collator Error in Eric6

Tags: python, pyqt

I'm totally a beginner in Python, and try to build my first pyQt project by Eric6. Then I got this problem. This warning comes whi
[Picture here: Warning: Could not create collator: 4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PDU3h.png)

This problem does not affect the basic functionality, and I can still finish the project as expected. But I wonder to know what this warning mean and how to avoid this warning. Thanks.

Versions:[Picture here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zG5PF.png)
System is Windows 10 x64, Python and pyQt are x32.

Comment: I changed my Python to V3.4.4, and changed pyQt to 5.5.0, then everything is ok.

Answer (score 0):

I changed my Python to V3.4.4, and changed pyQt to 5.5.0, then everything is ok.

Answer (score 0):

The developer of Eric6 explained like the following

> this is nothing caused by eric because there is no code creating q
>   QCollator object. However, due to the Qt documentation QLocale is
>   creating such an object. Therefore I assume an issue within Qt.